# Graphmath.Vector2 get nearest from a list of vectors

Tags: vector, elixir

I'm actually using `Graphmath.Vector2.near(a, b, r)` to detect if 2 vectors are in range.
What if i've got a list of `b` and i need to fetch `5` closest vectors to `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module doesn't export any distance calculation function but it's trivial to recreate:

```
def distance({x, y}, {u, v}) do
  dx = x - u
  dy = y - v
  :math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
end
```

Now you can sort a list by its distance to the point and take the first 5 like this:

```
point = {1, 2}
list = [{3, 4}, {5, 6}, ...]
nearest =
  list
  |> Enum.sort_by(&distance(&1, point))
  |> Enum.take(5)
```